# How to autocomplete with LDAP directory in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, contacts, ldap

Is it possible to have Mail pull matches from an LDAP directory as I type them in the To/Cc/Bcc fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding a new account in Contacts.app.

- **Contacts** > Add Account... > Other contacts account... Countinue
- Change `CardDAV` to `LDAP` and enter the Server Address

After doing this, Mail began to autocomplete addresses.